# No permission for camera access in Cordova webview for Android lollipop

Tags: cordova, webview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-permissions

i'm trying to make a hybride webapplication for Android 5.0, using the Webview in Cordova.
My Goal is to implement an App with webRTC features.

The problem i'm facing right now is, that the webview doesn't get permission to use the camera and microphone.

So i think i have to get access through a Cordova plugin and thats what i need help with.
Thats what i got so far, but it seems not to be working.

Any help and suggestions appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    private static final String TAG = Permissions.class.getSimpleName();
    private WebView mWebRTCWebView;

    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView,LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.initialize(cordova, webView);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    mWebRTCWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);

    setUpWebViewDefaults(mWebRTCWebView);

    mWebRTCWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    mWebRTCWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionRequest");
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                @Override
                public void run() {
                        if(request.getOrigin().toString().equals("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")) {
                        request.grant(request.getResources());
                    } else {
                        request.deny();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand where you want to put that code snippet. Replacing the webview from a cordova plugin doesn't sound like a good idea, imho this needs to be addressed from the cordova library.

I opened a PR: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/178